# Adding a Button for new entry in business form with using existing list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form

Can you help to resolve my query regarding on creating a button in a business form using existing list in SharePoint 2013.

Description:

Whenever user clicks on the button, it will open a new window for user registration using existing list in site contents.

I hope this clarifies. If not, please ask for further description.[image]

Comment: Is this Nintex Forms? If not, what designer is that?